# How to make good loop for this?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, loops, for-loop

I have this array :

```
$values = Array
(
    [0] => foo-1
    [1] => foo-2
    [2] => foo-3
    [3] => foo-4
    [4] => foo-5
    [5] => foo-6
    [6] => foo-7
    [7] => foo-8
    [8] => foo-9
    [9] => foo-10
    [10] => foo11
       [...]
    [30] => foo-31
    [31] => foo-32
)
```

I need to explode the array all the 13 values, and get this :

```
echo "foo-1, foo-2, foo-3, foo-4, foo-5, foo-6 [...], foo-13";

echo "foo-14, foo-15, foo-16, foo-17 [...], foo-26";

echo "foo-27, foo-28, foo-29, foo-30, foo-31, foo-32";
```

So, this is my code :

```
$nVal = count($values);
$nbTab = $nVal / 13;
$nbTab = round($nbTab, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
for ($cpt = 0; $cpt <= $nbTab-1; $cpt++) {
$line = "";
if($cpt == 0)
 $cptEntete = $cpt*12;
else
 $cptEntete = ($cpt*12)+1;
echo "Cpt entete :".$cptEntete;

if($cpt+1 == $nbTab){
 $jusque = $nVal;
}
else{
 if($cpt == 0)
  $jusque = 12;
 else
  $jusque = 12*($cpt+1);
}

for($cptEntete;$cptEntete <= $jusque;$cptEntete++){
 $line.= $cptEntete." ,";
}

echo $line."<br />";
```

The problem is that I don't arrive to obtain good lines with my 13 values by line :(

Can help me please ?

Comment: [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk) + [`join`](http://php.net/join)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get what your asking.  Do you mean that your for statement isn't working?  OR that it is working but not how you want it to?

Comment: My statement is not correct. I obtain a result, but the good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$values = array( /* your data */ );
$parts = array_chunk($values, 13);

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    echo implode(', ', $part);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = [];
for($i = 1; $i != 33; $i++)
    $myArray[] = "foo-$i";

$arrays = array_chunk($myArray, 13);
foreach($arrays as $array)
    echo implode(', ', $array)."\n";
```

[Sample to be found here](https://eval.in/186443).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo join(
    '<br>', // or whatever
    array_map(
        function (array $chunk) { return join(', ', $chunk); },
        array_chunk($values, 13)
    )
);
```

This [chunks](http://php.net/array_chunk) your array into 13 pieces each, joins all elements of each chunk with `,`, and then joins each chunk by `<br>` (replace that with whatever you want).

Comment: Thank, I didn't know array_chunk function